# Combining data from 2 tables and pivoting data from 1 of them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the current situation:

```
TableA
----------
SN     Date          OpsID
1234   2018-02-12    1
1324   2018-02-12    2
2134   2018-02-13    3

TableB
----------
Name     String      Number      OpsID
Value1   Hello       NULL        1
Value2   NULL        1111        1
Value3   Apples      NULL        1
Value1   There       NULL        2
Value2   NULL        2222        2
Value3   Pears       NULL        2
Value1   Baby        NULL        3
Value2   NULL        3333        3
Value3   Bananas     NULL        3
```

...and the result I'm looking for is:

```
SN    Date       Value1   Value2   Value3
1234  2018-02-12 Hello    1111     Apples
1324  2018-02-12 There    2222     Pears
2134  2018-02-13 Baby     3333     Bananas
```

The query I ran is obviously wrong because I'm getting mostly NULL and only Value data, but here it is anyway:

```
SELECT SN,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3
FROM(
   SELECT TableA.SN,
          TableA.Date,
          TableB.Name,
          TableB.String,
          TableB.Number
   FROM TableA,TableB
   WHERE
     TableA.OpsID = TableB.OpsID
   ORDER BY Date ASC
)Temp
PIVOT(
   MAX(Value)
   FOR Name in(
     Value1,Value2,Value3
   )
)PIV
```

Note that Value1 and Value3 are always VARCHAR and Value2 is always an INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select a.SN, a.date,
       max(case when b.Name = 'Value1' then coalesce(b.String, cast(b.Number as varchar(255))) end) as Value1,
       max(case when b.Name = 'Value2' then coalesce(b.String, cast(b.Number as varchar(255))) end) as Value2,
       max(case when b.Name = 'Value3' then coalesce(b.String, cast(b.Number as varchar(255))) end) as Value3
from tablea a inner join
     tableb b
     on b.OpsID = a.OpsID
group by a.SN, a.date;
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh. Worked as advertized!

Answer (score 1):

You combine String and Number into a single column in a subquery, and then pivot the values back out into their own columns like this:

```
SELECT SN, Date, Value1, CAST(Value2 AS INT) Value2, Value3 
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.SN, a.Date, B.Name, ISNULL(b.String, CAST(b.Number AS VARCHAR(10))) Value
    FROM TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.OpsID = B.OpsID
)sq1
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Name IN ([Value1], [Value2], [Value3]))sq2
```

Comment: Thank you, Max. The result structure came out correct but for some odd reason, records were missing.